# Hilbert space as an operator space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, operator-spaces

My textbook definition says that operator spaces are the closed subspaces of a $C^*$ algebra. I was wondering if we can give an operator space structure to a Hilbert space? My idea was the following mapping.

$f:H\to B(H)$ such that $h\mapsto \left<.,e\right>h$, where $e$ is any normal element. Am I doing this right?

Comment: While this is an isometric embedding $H\to B(H)$ (if $e$ has norm $1$), note that the product of two elements in the image will in general leave the image.

Comment: Is that a requirement for being an operator space?

Comment: Whats an "operator space"? Surely you should want the product to be well defined.

Comment: @s.harp No, an operator space is simply a closed subspace of $B(H)$ (or, equivalently, a $C^\ast$-algebra). You neither have a product nor can you take the adjoint inside an operator space. Somewhat surprisingly (at least to me), this is still a very useful notion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an isometric embedding if $e$ has norm $1$ (I guess that's what you mean by normal) and therefore defines an operator space structure on $H$.

However, note that every Banach space $E$ can be embedded isometrically into the $C^\ast$-algebra $C(B_{E^\ast})$, where $B_{E^\ast}$ is the unit ball of $E^\ast$ endowed with the weak$^\ast$ topology. So having *some* operator space structure is nothing that distinguishes Hilbert spaces from other Banach spaces.